# how to make this algorithm parallel with OpenMP?

Tags: openmp, towers-of-hanoi

Once again I'm stuck when using openMP in C++. This time I'm trying to implement a parallel Hanoi Tower .

```
sub Hanoi(n,D,A,I)
    if n =1 
    then 
        Move the disk D to A
    else              
        Hanoi(n-1,D,I,A)
        Move the disk D to A
        Hanoi(n-1,I,A,D)
    end
end-sub
```

how to make this algorithm parallel using OpenMp's instructions?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this algorithm can be OpenMPed, and I have my doubts that there's much parallelism in any towers of hanoi solution algorithm.   While this solution is recursive, unlike (say) quicksort it doesn't lend itself to a tasks based decomposition; there's no two branches you can do independantly.   And I doubt writing the algorithm differently would matter much; at any given time you want to move one disk from one pile to another (say, from 1 to 2).   You can't move the disks in pile 2 while this is happening, and you can't move the disks underneath on pile 1 until the top disk has been moved.  That only leaves one other top disk in the system, that in pile 3, to play with, and moving it from pile 3 to pile 3 is a no-op, so I just don't see there being any possible parallelism here.

Maybe if you were doing some sort of generalized problem with more than 3 piles there'd be something you could do but I still don't see it being easy.

Answer (score 2):

Use OpenMP `tasks` which were added to the specification at v3.0.  If you hit problems again, post your code.

Comment: what is this OpenMp's Tasks ?

Comment: I need openMp's instructuions please

Comment: Sorry, you're asking too much.  Perhaps someone else will write your code for you.

Comment: I don't ask that someone write the code for me but I ask  where place instructions in this algo?

Comment: I have examen and I need answer quickly please. and Thank you